# Facebook API web or mobile

Tags: php, facebook, api

Is there a way using Facebook API in PHP determine if online friends from my list friends use mobile or web, like in Facebook Messenger application on Android? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/elf8G.jpg)

I use this to get online friends:

```
SELECT uid, name, online_presence
        FROM user
        WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle', 'offline')
        AND uid IN (
            SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user
        )
```